# maximising the number of rows and variables whilst minimising the number of NaN values

Tags: r, python, missing-data, expectation-maximization

I am working on a data set which has a 84 variables recorded for a number of individuals. True to "real" data sets, there are many missing variables, NaN values and previous values carried forward (when looking at longitudinal data).

I am trying to find a way to maximise the number of variables present for the largest population, with no values carried forward. That is, how big can I make my population without loosing too many variables.

I have thought about using Expectation Maximisation, although I am not certain at this point how to apply it to this problem. For a lower dimensional problem it could have been possible to create a Venn diagram but in this higher dimensional space, its not really feasible.

I wondered how people have tackled this problem in the past and how you went about solving it. I will start (i think) my making a binary table indicating where values are present/not/carried forward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it not be better to impute them rather than selecting both variables and cases?

Comment: possibly. Im not sure how comfortable I am with imputation when I will building machine learning models on these values afterwards - as these values are being build on the rest of the data set doesnt this "taint" the validity? I know its common practice i just dont feel its particularly natural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the problem was perhaps simpler than first thought must have been a slip of the mind.

A simple clustered heatmap solved the problem with variables on one axis and individuals on the other. :)